# Sharepoint file management from Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

After years of avoiding Sharepoint I finally have to work with the thing. Working through the learning process and even booking courses but I'm going to have some dumb questions relating to stuff I need to solve immediately...

This one relates to manipulating documents on a sharepoint site from javascript on a separate web site. I'm getting my head around the rest api but am not sure whether this approach is right or what the error I'm seeing means.

So... All I want to do is copy a word document to the same location with a new name. I think, from the docs and examples I've found that I need something like:

```
http://mysites.blah.com/personal/me/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/personal/me/explore/doc1.docx')/copyto(strnewurl='/personal/me/explore/doc2.docx',boverwrite=false)
```

the error I'm getting back from the POST is

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.</m:message>
 </m:error>
```

So, I'm guessing that I'm missing an authentication element?
In my favour (possibly) is that I only have to provide this for users on Win machines on same network who will have access to the SP location and files

*EDIT
The suggestion from @Vivek below suggests that I need to make it clear that this has to work from a page outside of the Sharepoint environment. That prompts me to wonder if x-domain issues are a problem...

Comment: How are you executing the JS? Is it a Single Page Application? Check if this helps: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript

Comment: How are you executing the JS? Is it a Single Page Application? Check if this helps: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript

Comment: No, this has to work from a web page outside of the sharepoint environment

Comment: No, this has to work from a web page outside of the sharepoint environment

Comment: In that case I think you need to create a provider hosted App and use SP.RequestExecutor.js to execute your REST call. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx

Comment: In that case I think you need to create a provider hosted App and use SP.RequestExecutor.js to execute your REST call. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx